# Use aws_access_key_id and aws_access_secret_key in cloudformation to update a route 53 hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cloudformation

Given:
aws_access_key_id and aws_access_secret_key of an AWS account that administers an route 53 Hosted zone domain (say example.com).

Aim: Use the provided credentials as an other AWS user and update the Hosted zone with a record set (dummy.example.com is 56.22.55.11).

How? Possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrote a Lambda function that uses the credentials and update the hosted zone.
2. In the cloud formation, added a custom resource

Comment: Nice move of using the Custom Lambda Resource. Just a suggestion, given that you lambda you can perform a STS Assume role and then interact with Route 53 Record set of different AWS account. This way you don't have the need to hardcode the IAM Access Keys and rather can use the IAM Roles. Just an idea if you aren't using that already.

Comment: Thanks.I shall try it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use STS's AssumeRole functionality:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

The company where I work provides an open source tool for working with this a little easier, once you have it setup:

https://github.com/remind101/assume-role

Good luck!

Comment: Can you assume a role and perform the API calls via. CloudFormation ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean - you would assume a role, then make calls to the API for Cloudformation if you wanted to execute those cloudformation calls as that role.  Is that what you are asking?  Or are you asking if you can have a Cloudformation stack assume a role?  I don't believe that is possible, though that just seems like a different order of doing things that isn't super necessary.

Comment: the question was to make use of the CloudFormation to operate a different AWS account's Route53 record set. You have mentioned about STS as answer - so was wondering if you can do a STS Role Assume in the CloudFormation template / stack itself.

Comment: Ahh, ok, yeah - that's not possible in Cloudformation.  Cloudformation is specific to the account that you are creating resources in.  The solution you'd use in this case is to use AssumeRole to assume the role in the new account when you make the CreateStack or UpdateStack call to Cloudformation, but that results in the CF stack being in the target account, not your main account.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please provide a cloud formation example using aws_access_key_id and aws_access_secret_key  in it.